# Long form using colnames

Tags: r, tidyr, melt

Suppose I have the following data

```
 A <- c(4,4,4,4,4)
 B <- c(1,2,3,4,4)
 C <- c(1,2,4,4,4)
 D <- c(3,2,4,1,4)
 E <- c(4,4,4,4,5)

data <- data.frame(A,B,C,D,E)
data<- t(data)
colnames(data) = c("num1","freq1","freq2","freq3","totfreq")

> data
  num1 freq1 freq2 freq3 totfreq
A    4     4     4     4       4
B    1     2     3     4       4
C    1     2     4     4       4
D    3     2     4     1       4
E    4     4     4     4       5
```

I am trying to plot a grouped bar chart. The x-axis on both should be my variables `A:E`, and `y` is the values for `freq1`, `freq2`, `freq3` for each letter. I also need to keep the capability to plot variables `A:E` by values in `totfreq`.

I know I need to convert to long form but I'm having trouble with how my data is set up. Somehow I need `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E` need to stack into a column, another column that stacks `freq1`, `freq2`, `freq3`, `totfreq`, and then a last column with the values. Any advice how to accomplish this?

I'm looking to plot preferably in plotly, but ggplot would work too

Comment: So you want the heights of the bars to be the sum of freq1, freq2, freq3, and totfreq? By "then a last column with the values", which values do you mean?

Comment: Also, this seems to be a question on how to reshape your data in preparation, not on how to plot it. I'd suggest removing the `ggplot2` and `plotly` tags, since neither is needed to answer this question. They would instead factor into a possible follow-up question on building the plot once the data is in shape

Comment: The heights of the bar should be each of the values in the columns for the freq variables. So A would have 3 bars for the values in freq1,freq2,freq3. However I need it set up so I can alternatively grab just the totfreq so in a different graph I can plot where A would have just 1 bar, for the value in totfreq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you have a matrix but probably want a data frame. Making it a tibble will drop the row names, which is where your letters are stored, so

```
as.data.frame(data) %>% rownames_to_column("id")
```

will get you a data frame with a column `id` of letters.

You want to put this data into a long format by gathering all the `freq` columns. I'm then adding a column that gives the type of observation; this isn't necessary, but since you say you want to filter easily for one of two types—either the groups `freq1`, etc, or `totfreq`—this is a handy setup that I often use.

```r
library(tidyverse)

A <- c(4,4,4,4,4)
B <- c(1,2,3,4,4)
C <- c(1,2,4,4,4)
D <- c(3,2,4,1,4)
E <- c(4,4,4,4,5)

data <- data.frame(A,B,C,D,E)
data<- t(data)
colnames(data) = c("num1","freq1","freq2","freq3","totfreq")

data_long <- as.data.frame(data) %>%
  rownames_to_column("id") %>%
  gather(key = var, value = value, freq1:totfreq) %>%
  mutate(type = ifelse(var == "totfreq", "total", "by_group"))

head(data_long)
#>   id num1   var value     type
#> 1  A    4 freq1     4 by_group
#> 2  B    1 freq1     2 by_group
#> 3  C    1 freq1     2 by_group
#> 4  D    3 freq1     2 by_group
#> 5  E    4 freq1     4 by_group
#> 6  A    4 freq2     4 by_group
```

With the `type` column, it's really easy to filter by type for plotting. This would let you either pipe a filtered data frame into something like `ggplot`, or gives you a column to use for faceting or mapping onto an aesthetic.

```r
# for grouped bar chart
data_long %>% filter(type == "by_group")
#>    id num1   var value     type
#> 1   A    4 freq1     4 by_group
#> 2   B    1 freq1     2 by_group
#> 3   C    1 freq1     2 by_group
#> 4   D    3 freq1     2 by_group
#> 5   E    4 freq1     4 by_group
#> 6   A    4 freq2     4 by_group
#> 7   B    1 freq2     3 by_group
#> 8   C    1 freq2     4 by_group
#> 9   D    3 freq2     4 by_group
#> 10  E    4 freq2     4 by_group
#> 11  A    4 freq3     4 by_group
#> 12  B    1 freq3     4 by_group
#> 13  C    1 freq3     4 by_group
#> 14  D    3 freq3     1 by_group
#> 15  E    4 freq3     4 by_group

# for total freqs
data_long %>% filter(type == "total")
#>   id num1     var value  type
#> 1  A    4 totfreq     4 total
#> 2  B    1 totfreq     4 total
#> 3  C    1 totfreq     4 total
#> 4  D    3 totfreq     4 total
#> 5  E    4 totfreq     5 total
```

Created on 2018-05-17 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Holy crap this is perfect. Thank you! You rock. @camille

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to format the data so it could be processed, then let ggplot2 do the magic.

Find the code and output Graph below:

```
library(dplyr)         #To use mutate
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)      #To use melt
library(plotly)
A <- c(4,4,4,4,4)
B <- c(1,2,3,4,4)
C <- c(1,2,4,4,4)
D <- c(3,2,4,1,4)
E <- c(4,4,4,4,5)

data <- data.frame(A,B,C,D,E)
data2=names(data)
data<- t(data)
colnames(data) = c("num1","freq1","freq2","freq3","totfreq")

data=data.frame(data)                      
#Because mutate only works for data.frame not matrix

data=mutate(data,names=data2)%>%select("freq1","freq2","freq3","freq3","totfreq","names")  
# Adding names and removing num1

meltdata=melt(data,id.vars="names")        
#Because we need melted data to perform 

#Graph 1 (colourless and boring)
Graph1=ggplot(meltdata,aes(x=names,y=value))+geom_col()+facet_wrap(~variable)
#Graph 2 (Cool one)
Graph2=ggplot(meltdata,aes(x=names,y=value,fill=variable))+geom_col()+geom_text(label=meltdata$value,position="stack")

#Graph 3 is the best I guess
meltdata=mutate(meltdata,xval=1)
Graph3=ggplot(meltdata,aes(x=xval,y=value,fill=variable))+geom_col()+geom_text(label=meltdata$value,position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))+
  facet_grid(~names)+theme(panel.background = element_blank(),axis.text.x = element_blank(),
                           axis.ticks.x = element_blank())
Graph3
#If you like plotly so much then just use it by passing ggplot variable, But ggplot is better if you ask me
ggplotly(Graph1)
ggplotly(Graph2)
ggplotly(Graph3)
```

[image: Graph1 Output]

[image: Graph2 Output]

[image: Graph3 Output]